# Can I tell a remote git repo that my version of a branch is authoritative after a complex mistake?

Tags: git

**Update** I did `git push -f origin master:master`, which actually did bring the local and remote branches in sync, it just took a few minutes for the push to show up on bitbucket.

I've messed up bad. I tried to configure my local development and staging branches to simultaneously push to multiple remote branches. Once I though everything was configured correctly, I removed and .gitignored some demo code from the staging branch and pushed. I though I was doing this:

`git push` while on branch `master`: `master -> origin/master`

`git push` while on `development`: `development -> origin/development, development/master`

`git push` while on `staging`: `staging -> origin/staging, staging/master`

Now, I am unable to `git push origin master:master`; git says that `origin/master` is ahead of `master`. `git diff origin/master` shows me that the demo content that I had removed from the `staging` is also missing from `origin/master`. I decided to force the push (`git push -f origin master:master`) because I knew that my local copy was correct, there is no one else working on the part of the project that is under version control, and the repo is private. This did not synchronize `origin/master` to the local `master`. Git believes that they are in sync, but I have files on the local master branch that are not on `origin/master`. So, before I start figuring out how to untangle the remotes, how can I tell the `origin` repo that my copy of `master`'s history is the correct version? Or, is that another bad idea?

**Additional info**

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:<origin repo>.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:<origin repo>.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master             tracked
    staging            tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
    staging pushes to staging (fast-forwardable)

$ git remote show staging
* remote staging
  Fetch URL: git@heroku.com:<staging repo>.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:<staging repo>.git
  Push  URL: git@heroku.com:<staging repo>.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master  tracked
    staging tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    staging merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master  pushes to master  (local out of date)
    staging pushes to staging (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: `git push -f` should do it...or, as a workaround, checkout a new branch, delete master branch from remote, then push back to that.

Comment: It actually did work! It just took a while to show up on the bitbucket site. Thanks! Not sure if I should close, delete or update the question...

Comment: Yeah that happened to me the other day on bitbucket - I was going nuts for a good 10 minutes before I realized it was just delayed. I'd say just close, this is a pretty common issue.

Comment: "unclear what you're asking": the solution @jraede I mentioned actually did work, so the question is confusing because it is based on the premise that the solution did not work.

Comment: @DanRoss I suggest you post that answer yourself, include some documentation references and accept the answer, otherwise this will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the repository is private and no one else had worked on it since before I started messing with the remotes, which is what led to the problem, I had the option of doing a forced push to correct the remote history. I didn't trust the configuration of my local repo, so I specified everything explicitly:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

saved my butt. `-f` to forced git to ignore the incorrect history of the remote, `origin` is the name of the remote repo, and `master:master` means take the local `master` branch and push it to the remote `master` branch (`[local branch]:[remote branch]`).

I though that this didn't work because it took a few minutes for the changes to become visible on the bitbucket site. If anyone else is in this situation, have faith in the --force and give the internets a moment to catch up.

The [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book is an excellent guide. The section [Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) explains the `git push` options in detail.